# Ubuntu lags severely on log-in screen and won't go any further

Tags: 12.04, boot, login

I have just installed 12.04 LTS alongside my Windows 7 OS. I restarted my computer and loaded Ubuntu from the boot screen. The purple Ubuntu screen shows and goes away and the log-in screen appears. However, the system seems to be really slow. Mouse input is extremely lagged, although keyboard input is nominal. After I input my password, the system never logs in. The log in screen went away the first time I logged in, but it wouldn't do anything else, and all subsequent log-in attempts have resulted in nothing happening. In all accounts, the cursor would still move but was still very lagged.

My system specs are as follows:

Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.120305-1505)

Language: English (Regional Setting: English)

System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.

System Model: Inspiron M5030

BIOS: BIOS Date: 01/09/10 15:17:22 Ver: 08.00.10

Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) II P360 Dual-Core Processor (2 CPUs), ~2.3GHz

Memory: 4096MB RAM

Available OS Memory: 3836MB RAM

Windows Dir: C:\windows

DirectX Version: DirectX 11

Graphics Card name: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250

Manufacturer: ATI Technologies Inc.

Chip type: ATI display adapter (0x9712)

Display Memory: 1914 MB

Dedicated Memory: 252 MB

Shared Memory: 1661 MB

Current Mode: 1920 x 1080 (32 bit) (60Hz)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).